# Embedded Unity Application not displaying in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine, embed

I currently have an iOS app and want to embed a Unity application as a subview within my application. I'v been struggling with this over the last couple months on and off.

I was getting issues with building my application for some time, but now it is building and running properly (almost). The view I would like the Unity application to display within isn't displaying anything.

For reference I am using **Unity 2019.1.12f1** and **XCode 10.3**

I am NOT using Vuforia, its just a very basic Unity app with a model and basic animation.

My AppDelegate file is:

```swift
 @UIApplicationMain
 class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

 var window: UIWindow?

 var application: UIApplication?


 @objc var currentUnityController: UnityAppController!

 var isUnityRunning = false

 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
     self.application = application
     unity_init(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv)

     currentUnityController = UnityAppController()
     currentUnityController.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

     // first call to startUnity will do some init stuff, so just call it here and directly stop it again
     startUnity()
     stopUnity()


     return true
 }

 func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {f isUnityRunning {
         currentUnityController.applicationWillResignActive(application)
     }
 }

 func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
     if isUnityRunning {
         currentUnityController.applicationDidEnterBackground(application)
     }
 }

 func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
     if isUnityRunning {
         currentUnityController.applicationWillEnterForeground(application)
     }
 }

 func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

     if isUnityRunning {
         currentUnityController.applicationDidBecomeActive(application)
     }
 }

 func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
     if isUnityRunning {
         currentUnityController.applicationWillTerminate(application)
     }

 }


 func startUnity() {
     if !isUnityRunning {
         isUnityRunning = true
         currentUnityController.applicationDidBecomeActive(application!)
     }
 }

 func stopUnity() {
     if isUnityRunning {
         currentUnityController.applicationWillResignActive(application!)
         isUnityRunning = false
     }
 }
```

I am then using this snippet of code to display the code Unity in the subview

```swift
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
 appDelegate.startUnity()
 self.unityView = UnityGetGLView()
```

I am absolutely baffled as to why this is not working. Any help would be much appreciated.

Hope this is enough information. Please let me know if there is anything else you need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delegate looks all good, but your ViewController is missing some pieces. Try this code:

```
import UIKit

class UnityViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            appDelegate.startUnity()
            showUnitySubView()
        }
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            appDelegate.stopUnity()
        }
    }

    func showUnitySubView() {
        if let unityView = UnityGetGLView() {
            // insert subview at index 0 ensures unity view is behind current UI view
            view?.insertSubview(unityView, at: 0)

            unityView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            let views = ["view": unityView]
            let w = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "|-0-[view]-0-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
            let h = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-64-[view]-49-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
            view.addConstraints(w + h)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked ALMSOT amazingly! For some reason the unity view does not load the first time the relevant view controller appears, but upon disappearing and then reappearing the unity view will appear

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solves your problem.
I'm using this exact ViewController and it works on the first appearance, so i think the problem with not showing is somewhere else. Can you show more Code about how you are presenting the ViewController and how you initialise Unity?

Comment: The view controller is my Initial View Controller which is within a Navigation Controller. I feel as though it may be because Unity is not ready to be displayed at the time I am trying to display it

Comment: To further support my above comment I have found that it works okay when I call the startUnity() and showUnitySubView() methods upon a button press a couple seconds after the display shows

Comment: @AwaisHussain you could add a KVO which would automatically launch your Unity screen when it is ready. This was a nice addition for me to make it smoother:
https://github.com/blitzagency/ios-unity5/issues/14